# PHP is loading the same content endlessly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, infinite-loop

How can i prevent it from loading the same table row all over again and never stopping ? My head can't take it ... I know i somehow created an infinite loop so i searched on internet and i saw people doing almost the same but somehow it worked for them.

```
include_once "additional_code/dbh.inc.php";

session_start();

$savedUsername = $_SESSION["username"];

if (!isset($savedUsername) || empty($savedUsername)) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender = $savedUsername";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row > 0) {
    echo "it works";

    while($row) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($row["sender"] . ": " . $row["msg"]);
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "It doesn't work";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
while($row) {
```

You are effectively creating an endless loop. Because `$row` is a defined variable, it's a turthy value - this makes it essentially become

```
while (true) {
```

What you want instead is to fetch each row, meaning that you must supply the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` as the argument to your `while`. You also want to check the *number of rows* instead, as you are now fetching the first row (and it will not be visible in the loop).

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0) {
    echo "it works";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($row["sender"] . ": " . $row["msg"]);
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "It doesn't work";
}
```

You should also be aware that your code is vulnerable for SQL-injection attacks, and you should use prepared statements with MySQLi and bind your values instead of injecting the variables directly in your query.

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row > 0)
{
    echo "it works";

   while($row)
   {
      echo htmlspecialchars($row["sender"] . ": " . $row["msg"]);
      echo "<br><br>";
   }
}
```

To this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo htmlspecialchars($row["sender"] . ": " . $row["msg"]);
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first count with `mysqli_num_rows` if your query contains any records or not and then can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` if records are there like below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender = $savedUsername";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count > 0) {
    echo "it works";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($row["sender"] . ": " . $row["msg"]);
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
 }
```

Always use **Prepared Statements** to make Queries more **Secure**